# Why are the episodes of Ooyasan Wa Shishunki so short?

Tags: ooyasan-wa-shishunki

This anime runs incredibly fast, even for some of the shorter, 4-koma series I've seen. The story progression, if you want to call it that, seems to skip forward drastically off screen. When watching this, it seems like the characters voices have actually been sped up to maybe 1.5x speed. The latest episode, episode 3, was just under 2 minutes long.

From the show's [MyAnimeList page](http://myanimelist.net/anime/31621/Ooyasan_wa_Shishunki) I was able to find out that it's aired weekly, on Saturday nights at 22:27 JST. Does the time slot it got have something to do with how short this anime is, or is there some other reason?

Comment: Well, the 22:00-22:30 time block on MX consists of "Nijiiro Days" for the first 15 minutes; the associated variety show "club Rainbow" for 12 more minutes; and then this. On SUN, it's 25 minutes of "Kirari Keizai" and then this. But I suspect the causation runs "we're going to produce a 2-minute show" → "let's find a 2-minute slot to put it in" rather than "we can get a 2-minute slot" → "let's make the show 2 minutes long".

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes 4komas are adapted into full-time anime episodes and it doesn't look really good because they have to be diluted with filler content (Looking at you, Azumanga). It may not look good, so some studios apparently choose to ignore this "normal" time format and just do what they think it's best in very short episodes.

Also, short formats are common for anime contests, where the quality matters above episode duration. This way both animation studios and directors can show off their skills in adapting or making an original title into animation.

As for airing time slots, anime is usually not earning any money by itself, but rather by ads shown during and around their airing time. A 3-minute episode doesn't work very well for earning money this way, so TV channels usually give it a slot that doesn't earn them too much money anyways.